# Find the limit of the following expression $\lim_{x\to1}(3 \sqrt[3]{x}-2\sqrt{x})^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1}(3 \sqrt[3]{x}-2\sqrt{x})^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}$

How is this limit taken?

I was able to convert this expression to the following form

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1} \exp(\log_x(3 \sqrt[3]{x}-2\sqrt{x}))$

however, this did not clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the limit using the standard limit $\lim_{y\to 0}(1+y)^{1/y}= e$ and $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}= 1$ as follows using the substitution $x=e^{6u}$ and considering $u \to 0$:

\begin{eqnarray*} (3\sqrt[3]{x}-2\sqrt{x})^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}
& \stackrel{x=e^{6u}}{=} & \left(3e^{2u} - 2e^{3u}\right)^{\frac 1{6u}} \\
& = & e^{\frac 13}\left(\left(\left(1+2(1-e^u)\right)^{\frac 1{1-e^u}}\right)^{\frac{1-e^u}{u}}\right)^{\frac 16} \\
& \stackrel{u \to 0}{\longrightarrow} & e^{\frac 13}\left(e^2\right)^{-\frac 16} = 1
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Notice that

$$\log_x(3\sqrt[3]{x}-2\sqrt{x})=\frac{1}{3}+\log_x(3-2\sqrt[6]{x})=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\log(3-2\sqrt[6]{x})}{\ln(x)}$$

And now apply L’Hopital.